# Integration of graphql microservices using feign client

Tags: java, api, graphql, microservices, feign

There are 2 graphql microservices that are needed to be integrated. In one of the graphql schema there is pagination present along with validation.
For the second graphql microservice to consume, we are using feign client but cannot pass the query variables present in the pagination part of the graphql query.
Any other way to connect graphql microservices that would pass the query variables paramaters?

Comment: I am starting to work on this now, I can share the results after I am done. The first important finding is that you need to pass `query` parameter in the request entity which contains the query json (or an entity representing the json, I guess). Just do the POST to the /graphql path of the target service.

Comment: @havryliuk I'm working on something similar rn. Although, I imagine sending an interpolated string as request body would work here. 